# Curl in Docker entrypoint script

Tags: docker, splunk

I am modifying [this repo](https://github.com/outcoldman/docker-splunk/tree/master/universalforwarder) to automatically configure a forwarder.  It has a Dockerfile that specifies an entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

In that file, I am trying to curl an AWS instance ID and put it in a file somewhere for Splunk to use.  If I create a `splunk` network as the repo states, everything works fine and I'm on my way.  I can't quite put together what this network is actually doing, and why it works as opposed to just specifying a seemingly identical `bridge` network.  I saw the Docker documentation on `--net` but can someone help explain what is going on here?  If I don't pass `--net` in the Docker run command, a simple curl command will just hang forever.

Comment: > and why it works as opposed to just specifying a seemingly identical bridge network
What isn't working? You haven't provided any errors, commands, or relevant debugging information.

Comment: If I don't pass --net in the Docker run command, a simple curl command will just hang forever.

Comment: What are you trying to `curl`? Something outside / inside other network?

Comment: On the network. It's the AWS metadata URL

Comment: @smugcloud docker network?

Comment: @outcoldman not sure what you mean but there is a network present.  it seems that I have to specify either the host network, or splunk.  Splunk was just a basic network so I'm not sure why that was important.  I thought about sending you a direct message so any insight you can provide is appreciated.  Thanks for putting that image together!

Comment: @smugcloud I don't think that issue you are seeing anyhow related to my image (and you are welcome :)). I am asking about from where you are actually trying to curl, because of issues like https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/18354. Also `--net splunk` is just an example, I use it to link multiple containers.

Comment: @outcoldman Hmm, that issue could be related.  The URL I am trying to hit is the AWS metadata service: 169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id

Comment: If you are trying to curl the AWS meta-data URL from a container then why don't you edit your question for the relevant debugging data? What is the exact commands you ran to test this? What was the output? Have you tried just starting an interactive `debian` or other base image without `--net host` to test?